# How to Parse a Retrofit JSON Response with Dynamic Keys and Variable Object Names in Android?

Tags: android, json, dynamic, retrofit

I have used **retrofit** as calling API in android,

And I am getting response like this.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "garden": {
      "id": "31",
      "name": "Garden",
      "count": 307
    },
    "balcony": {
      "id": "32",
      "name": "balcony",
      "count": 451
    },
    "Parking": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Parking",
      "count": 791
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

- Here the data is in the form of object
- And inside it garden, balcony, parking etc. are also in the form of objects.

**Challange is**

```json
"garden":{...},"balcony":{...},"Parking":{...}
```

I have to show all this in the form of a list.

And the big challenge is that -> **I will not know how many other objects like garden, balcony, parking etc will come in response.**

If "data" had come in the form of a JSONArray, I would have been able to handle it by building some logic, but here "data" is a JSONObject.

How can I solve this? please help

**What have I tried?**

Fetched `data` as a `String` Like...

```kotlin
@SerializedName("data") val data: String,
```

But it is throwing a failure, `Error:` and it is saying that you are asking for a string, but "data" is an object.

Second, got the "data" fetched as a JSONObject Like...

```kotlin
@SerializedName("data") val data: JSONObject,
```

Yes, it is working, but when I am printing logs of the "data", I am getting empty JSONObject like.

> "data" : {}

**This is code that can handle the response, but it is not useful**

```kotlin
data class MainData(
    @SerializedName("data") val data: Facilities,
)

data class Facilities(
    @SerializedName("garden") val garden: FacilitiesData,
    @SerializedName("balcony") val balcony: FacilitiesData,
    @SerializedName("parking") val parking: FacilitiesData,
    ...
)

data class FacilitiesData(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int? = 0,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("count") val count: Int? = 0,
)
```

Comment: I also have the same issue. Please inform me once you get the solution

Comment: You can use `Map` Map<key, value> it will store data with various keys. It might help you to parse JSON with dynamic keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse like...

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, Vitals> result;
```

Comment: Thanks @ankita-panchal your response was most helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a response class like this

```
data class MyResponse(val Map<String, FacilitiesData>)
```

Then you can access each `FacilitiesData` item via its string key

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. This is how I handled a dynamic JSON object using Retrofit. I hope it can help you.

I have a dynamic JSON object inside my error body. This is the JSON structure.

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "login": [
      "Email or phone number is invalid..."
    ] 
  }
}
```

And instead of 'login', this could be any other word.

So, I handled it using this piece of code and extracted the value from the dynamic JSON object.

```
                if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                    val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(), ErrorResponse::class.java)
                    val message : String? = errorResponse.message
                    val errors : Map<String , List<String>>?  = errorResponse.errors
                    errors?.forEach { (key : String, value: List<String>) ->
                        errorMessage = value.joinToString() //Email or phone number is invalid...
                    }
                }
```

And this is my **ErrorResponse** model:

```
data class ErrorResponse(
    @SerializedName("errors")
    val errors: Map<String , List<String>>?,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? //The given data was invalid.
)
```

I know this is a little bit different from your JSON structure, but it follows the same concept, and I hope my solution can help you.